# Get sum using DATE_FORMAT() and IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query that looks a little bit like this :

```
SELECT sum(X) as qty 
FROM ...
WHERE ...
AND DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m%d') IN (20100601,20100701,20100801,20100901,20101001)
```

This obviously is giving me a result that looks like :

```
qty
226761
```

But what I'm looking to get is the quantity for each separate date format :

```
qty      date
16000   20100601
57000   20100701
23000   20100801
30000   20100901
72000   20101001
```

I'm new to SQL so I have no idea how to go about getting that specific format. I'm just looking for help of the algorithms, you can use random table names or row names I don't mind. I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m%d')`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m%d') datex, sum(X) as qty 
FROM ...
WHERE ...
AND date IN ('20100601','20100701','20100801','20100901','20101001')
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: But your query is not doing this, and you don't need `DATE_FORMAT` at all here really.

Comment: What is my query not doing?

Comment: `You need to group by DATE_FORMAT` ... but you never did that

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but he IS grouping by date which is equal to `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m%d')` (see his select), no ?

Comment: Why? I can `group by date` and select `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y%m%d')`, can't I?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT date(date), sum(X) as qty 
FROM ...
WHERE ... AND
      date(date) IN ('2010-06-01', '2010-07-01', '2010-08-01', '2010-09-01', '2010-10-01')
GROUP BY date(date);
```

You'll notice that I removed the `date_format()`.  Converting dates to strings is a bad habit and there is no need to do this.  If `date` has no time component (as suggested by its name), then `date()` is not even needed.

EDIT:

The use of `date_format()` suggests that your dates are stored as *dates*.  If this is not true, then you can simply do:

```
SELECT date, sum(X) as qty 
FROM ...
WHERE ... AND
      date IN ('20100601', '20100701', '20100801', '20100901', '20101001')
GROUP BY date;
```

Drop the single quotes if the date are numbers.

Comment: Assuming `date` is already a date column, then the cast might not even be necessary.

Comment: My dates are in this format `20100901` tho, but thanks for the idea!